# How do you use BeautifulSoup to select a tag depending on its children and siblings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract quotes from 2012 Obama-Romney presidential debate.  Problem is [the site](http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=102317) is not well organized.  So the structure looks like this:

```
<span class="displaytext">
    <p>
        <i>OBAMA</i>Obama's first quotes
    </p>
    <p>More quotes from Obama</p>
    <p>Some more Obama quotes</p>

    <p>
        <i>Moderator</i>Moderator's quotes
    </p>
    <p>Some more quotes</p>

    <p>
        <i>ROMNEY</i>Romney's quotes
    </p>
    <p>More quotes from Romney</p>
    <p>Some more Romney quotes</p>
</span>
```

Is there a way to select a `<p>` whose first child is an `i` that has the text `OBAMA` AND all it's `p` siblings UNTIL you hit the next `p` whose first child is an `i` that does not have the text `Obama` ??

Here is what I tried so far, but it is only grabbing the first `p` ignoring the siblings

```
input = '''<span class="displaytext">
        <p>
            <i>OBAMA</i>Obama's first quotes
        </p>
        <p>More quotes from Obama</p>
        <p>Some more Obama quotes</p>

       <p>
           <i>Moderator</i>Moderator's quotes
       </p>
       <p>Some more quotes</p>

       <p>
           <i>ROMNEY</i>Romney's quotes
       </p>
       <p>More quotes from Romney</p>
       <p>Some more Romney quotes</p>
       </span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(input)
debate_text = soup.find("span", { "class" : "displaytext" })
president_quotes = debate_text.find_all("i", text="OBAMA")

for i in president_quotes:
    siblings = i.next_siblings
    for sibling in siblings:
        print(sibling)
```

Which only prints `Obama's first quotes`

Answer (score 2):

I think a kind of [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)-like solution will work here. Like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(input, 'lxml')
debate_text = soup.find("span", { "class" : "displaytext" })
obama_is_on = False
obama_tags = []
for p in debate_text("p"):
    if p.i and 'OBAMA' in p.i:
        # assuming <i> is used only to indicate speaker
        obama_is_on = True
    if p.i and 'OBAMA' not in p.i:
        obama_is_on = False
        continue
    if obama_is_on:
        obama_tags.append(p)
print(obama_tags)

[<p>
<i>OBAMA</i>Obama's first quotes
        </p>, <p>More quotes from Obama</p>, <p>Some more Obama quotes</p>]
```

Answer (score 2):

The other Obama quotes are siblings of the `p`, not the `i`, so you'll need to find the siblings of `i`'s parent. As you're looping through those siblings, you can stop when one has an `i`. Something like this:

```
for i in president_quotes:
    print(i.next_sibling)
    siblings = i.parent.find_next_siblings('p')
    for sibling in siblings:
        if sibling.find("i"):
            break
        print(sibling.string)
```

which prints:

```
Obama's first quotes

More quotes from Obama
Some more Obama quotes
```